# xDebug session never starts

Tags: eclipse, settings, xdebug

I've just change my OS to Windows 7 64.
I have Apache 2.2, PHP 5.3 (32bit) TS and Eclipse 3.7 (64bit) with PDT installed on my machine.

xDebug section in my php.ini

```
zend_extension = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.4-5.3-vc9.dll"
xdebug.auto_trace = 0
xdebug.collect_includes = 1
xdebug.collect_params = 0
xdebug.collect_return = 0
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.extended_info = 1
xdebug.idekey = "STATION24$"
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 100
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\WINDOWS\temp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "xdebug_profile.%p"
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.remote_log = 1
xdebug.remote_mode = "req"
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
xdebug.show_exception_trace = 0
xdebug.show_local_vars = 0
xdebug.show_mem_delta = 1
xdebug.trace_format = 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\WINDOWS\Temp"
xdebug.trace_output_name = "trace.%c"
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 5
```

In Eclipse I've configured PHP->Debug section as shown on images:

[image]
[image]
[image]

And now, when I try to launch debug, Eclipse freeze at starting debug session.

[image]

So, I'd read about this problem in past, people say this is because some application use xDebug port (in my case 9001), but I've checked, no other use this port, only xDebug do.
My firewall disabled, so no one application can block connection to xDebug. And one thing - "debug as CLI application" works well, only "debug as Web application" does not work.

I don't know what to do, please help.

Comment: Problem has solved. I've just forgot to set browser in Eclipse settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you run into problems and you don't know whether the Xdebug side is not working, or the IDE's side, then from Xdebug 2.2.0RC1 the remote debug log will also log connection issues.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, you mention PHP TS. Maybe you should use xdebug TS too then?
(Although I read everywhere that lately you better not use TS at all, so might want to change php not TS or so).